# Loading program with OpenOCD

Tags: jtag, openocd

I'm on a system with external flash, so I'm unable to program it easily. However, I can load firmware through JTAG - OpenOCD - GDB chain. I automated it as far as I'm able with `bash` and `.gdbinit`, but it's, well... shit. Doesn't work most of the time, I have to constantly fix it by hand or power cycle the board.

So I was wondering, does anyone knows a way to load a program using only OpenOCD?

In essence I'm looking to implement following GDB commands in OpenOCD script:

```
monitor reset halt
load
continue
```

EDIT:

The board is for [Kendryte K210 risc-v microcontroller](https://kendryte.com/downloads/). The board is using an external flash and normally programmed through USB-UART converter (bootloader flag maybe?).

They've got [their own fork of OpenOCD](https://github.com/kendryte/openocd-kendryte). I'm pretty sure I can't use OpenOCD's `program` or `flash` commands, it's the first thing I tried.

Comment: What's your hardware? OpenOCD does support flashing on many configurations: http://openocd.org/doc/html/Flash-Programming.html

Comment: You can set up OpenOCD so that you can telnet into it, and use commands from that interface.  That's how my workflow with the tool goes -- I command flash loads from OpenOCD, and often use it for inspecting the device's memory-mapped peripherals without going through GDB.  You do realize that there's a chance that the problem is the custom fork of OpenOCD, yes?